# Vuejs multiply components and one parent emit

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, vue-component

I have parent component. It send formdata to server. Also i have child components for upload files to server. I need emit event from child to parent when child finish uploading files, but if i emit event from each component it generate event to parent and parent method call twice.
I need call parent function only once!

Do you have any ideas how i can do that correctly?
P.S. on one page can be one or more child components.

Comment: Similar codeopen `https://codepen.io/ihorvimmi/pen/BVJPMo`

Comment: You should provide a [mcve]

Comment: https://codepen.io/ihorvimmi/pen/BVJPMo

Comment: @IgorZinchenko, in the example you provided events are emitted only once per each component. I am not clear on what you are asking. If you want to display firing of the event with same name only once, you need a variable on the parent that will track if such event has fired.